# How to download files from url to the server via ssh

Tags: file-upload, ssh, download, server

My internet is slow relatively, So I need to download ubuntu server iso to my server directly via ssh connection. 
My server based on **VMware ESXi**.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to the server as usually:

   ```
   ssh your_server
   ```
2. Download the ISO to the server using `wget` from direct url (install `wget` if not installed yet):

   ```
   wget https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso
   ```

   or just using `http`:

   ```
   wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso
   ```

Comment: wget is installed of course. and I tried many times this code and it doesn't work. display message `wget: not an http or ftp url: https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso`

Comment: what system are you using on that server, that does not support HTTPS? Current `wget` certainly supports HTTPS. Otherwise try the url with HTTP only (edited answer).

Comment: I am using **VMware ESXi** server and my local server is **Ubuntu 16.04**.This message when I tried without HTTPS `Connecting to releases.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.160:80)
wget: can't open 'ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso': File exists
`